# How to extract all rows that have the same value in a column as one of the rows?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that contains `name` and `class`. Each `name` belongs to one `class`. Here is a sample dataset.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(name = c("John","Smith","Jane","Ruby","Emerald","Jasmine","Tulip"),
                 class = c(1,2,3))
```

I'd like to get all names that belong to the same class as a particular person, say, for example, John. I don't know how exactly his name appears in the dataset so I do a `grep` beforehand, and get this:

```
DT[class %in% DT[name %in% grep("john", DT[, name], ignore.case = T, value = T), class],
   name]
```

`%in%` is to ensure that if there is more than one person named John, I catch them all. Is there a prettier way to do this, perhaps using join?

EDIT: If I knew the name exactly and it occurred just once, the above would compress to,

```
DT[class == DT[name == "John", class], name]
```

What I'm looking for is something like a "chaining" solution, where I can do away with the nestedness as it seems inelegant.

Comment: I am not a `data.table` person but perhaps this? `DT[with(DT, class == class[name == "John"])]`

Comment: You can use a join: `DT[.(class[name == "John"]), on=.(class), name]` See `?data.table` and the vignettes on http://r-datatable.com/Getting-Started for details. If you only have a pattern for the name, do `name %like% patt` instead of `name == "John"`

Comment: thanks for your answers! @RonakShah, in a data.table, `with` is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Frank, what I was looking for is,

```
DT[.(class[name %like% "John"]), on=.(class), name]
```

Also, based on @RonakShah's answer, this works.

```
DT[class == class[name %like% "John"])]
```

It had slipped my mind that lists can be indexed in this way.